# NSUserDefaults if data equal to something then NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I created a simple app when you click on a button it saves first click with `1` second with `1` and so. So, I tried to check if the first click equal to 1 then `NSLog` but it didn't worked.

Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
//Once the user click on the button it adds 1
static int num = 0;
num+=1;

//Save the number for key "saved and the number" ex: if number is 1 so for key is "saved 1"
NSString *dataa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", num];
NSString *fkey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"saved %i", num];
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:dataa forKey:fkey];
[def synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)load:(id)sender
{
//load the data forkey "saved 1" wich will be '1'
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadd = [def objectForKey:@"saved 1"];
NSLog(@"%@",loadd); 

//and here I failed, here I want to check if [def objectForKey:@"saved 1"] == '1' 
//then NSLog@"Yes" but it NSLogs "NOO"
NSString *no = @"1";

if(loadd == no){
   NSLog(@"YES");
  }else{
        NSLog(@"NOO");
    }

}
```

So what is the issue here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to connect the `add:` method to proper event in IB? Try `NSLogging` the data and key when saving them. Also (when you get this working) you shouldn't compare strings with `==` - use `isEqualToString` instead.

Comment: You cannot compare strings via `==`, as you would compare the pointers. Try using `
isEqualToString:`

Comment: @Krumelur, why don't you post your suggestion as an answer so the OP can accept it? That way other readers will know that the question has been answered correctly.

Comment: I didn't really read the issue. This was just something I spotted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `[loadd isEqualToString:no]` instead, that compares strings.

here is the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: how come this got too many upvotes in 1 minute. pardon me @vborra

Comment: @santhu: well, an answer does not have to be complex to get upvoted - it usually just needs to be correct

Comment: @rokjarc is right, sometimes the best answers come from the simplest solutions.